# How to access an object defined in a function from another function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am building a simple GUI app to manage priorities. I'm stuck with accessing an object defined in a function from another function, in this instance accessing **root** in the function **createWindow** from **display()**. The window opens but there is no label, and this is what it gives me when I quit the program:

> /usr/bin/python3.5 /home/cali/PycharmProjects/priorities/priorities.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/cali/PycharmProjects/priorities/priorities.py", line 34, in
>   
>       c.main()   File "/home/cali/PycharmProjects/priorities/priorities.py", line 31, in
>   main
>       g.display()   File "/home/cali/PycharmProjects/priorities/priorities.py", line 22, in
>   display
>       Label(root, NameError: name 'root' is not defined
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Here is what I have done so far:

```
# priorities.py
#   GUI program to manage priorities

from tkinter import *

class Priority:
    pass

class GuiPart:

    def createWindow(self):

        root = Tk()
        root.resizable(width = False, height = False)
        root.title = "Priorities"
        root.mainloop()

        return root

    def display(self):

        Label(root,
              text = "testes").grid(row = 0, column = 1)

class Client:

    def main(self):

        g = GuiPart()
        g.createWindow()
        g.display()

c = Client()
c.main()
```

I'm using Python 3.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you probably want to do is store root as an instance variable of the GuiPart class once createWindow() is called:

```
class GuiPart:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = createWindow()

    def createWindow(self):

        root = Tk()
        root.resizable(width = False, height = False)
        root.title = "Priorities"
        root.mainloop()

        return root

    def display(self):

        Label(self.root,
              text = "testes").grid(row = 0, column = 1)
```

What happens now is that root is stored as g.root when you create the GuiPart instance. Your main function would just look like this then:

```
def main(self):

    g = GuiPart()
    g.display()
```

You could also do it like this:

```
class GuiPart:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def createWindow(self):

        root = Tk()
        root.resizable(width = False, height = False)
        root.title = "Priorities"
        root.mainloop()

        self.root = root

    def display(self):

        Label(self.root,
              text = "testes").grid(row = 0, column = 1)
```

Then your main would be like this:

```
def main(self):
    g = GuiPart()
    g.createWindow()
    g.display()
```

Comment: First version gives a NameError: name 'createWindow' is not defined, whereas the second one gives this on exiting: can't invoke "label" command: application has been destroyed, and you forgot (?) main(self)

Comment: It sounds like you have other problems in your code besides what was asked about in the original question.

Comment: Yeah, it does. Sorry.

Comment: No worries, I recommend going through a tutorial on TK it can be pretty confusing IMO. http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/

Comment: Actually this one is better https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm

Answer (score 0):

You want to use class attributes here, like this

```
class GuiPart:
    def createWindow(self):
        root = Tk()
        root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        root.title = "Priorities"
        root.mainloop()

        self.root = root

        return root


    def display(self):
        Label(self.root,
              text="testes").grid(row=0, column=1)
```

Note how the value of `root` gets assigned to `self.root`, and later read from `self.root` again. `self` can be used for storing object attributes on for the lifetime of an object.

Comment: AttributeError: 'GuiPart' object has no attribute 'root'